# In Kubuntu 22.04 suddenly keyboard gives wrong scancodes, how to repair without reboot?

Tags: keyboard, kubuntu

On my TUXEDO Notebook BU1406 (N240BU) I have installed Kubuntu 22.04 LTS. And I have configured it to have under Konsole about 10 windows,in each a first-level shell bash for user kubuntu and a second-level bash for user root.

I do not use the GUI desktop but always the terminal emulator.

This is yet running in Try modus since I was not able to install due to some error messages (presumably bugs).

Since updating to this Kubuntu version it often happens that during my typing suddenly the keyboard becomes mal-functioning. I.e. for many keys on the right half, more precisly: on the RHS of the key "z", not the correspunding letter is given to the software but instead a one-figure digit. I.e. instead of "l" it is "5" or "3" or so.

In previous weeks to restore the keyboard I always used my found workaround: type key sequence Fn F12 to go into Energysaving mode and type again Fn F12 to come back into operational mode.

The normal ways to use "tset" or "reset" were of no help.

Now since a few days I am again in such a faulty keyboard state. But now Fn F12 has no effect.

But now the workaround is: type "Fn" follwd by "l" gives correct "l", "Fn" followed by "o" gives correct "o", etc.

The mis-function of the keyboard happens on a very low level. The utility showkey shows with all its options the wrong response to the typed key. Even the scan code of the key is wrong.

Therefore my question is:

Which software of the operating system is responsible for making the scan code to a typed key.

I need to to overwrite this small part of corrupted code in the running OS with a correct code.

Regards

== 25.06.2023 13:11 addon:

some more details:

With Ctrl-Alt-F1 to Ctrl-Alt-F6 I can switch to the basic virtual consoles tty1 .. tty6.

These tty1 .. tty6 are not broken. There key "l" gives "l", etc.

But for me these tty1 .. tty6 are very hard to use: the keyboard layout is us, and the font size is very, very small, and I have forgotten how to resize the font (like with Ctrl-+).

This means, the relevant portion of code that makes from typed key "l" the scan code for letter "l" is here not corrupted. So I have to get this code and apply it to the terminal emulators XTERM under "Konsole".

Regards

Comment: Is this a keyboard *without* a numpad? Maybe some keys are extra labelled and normally act as a numpad when you hold `Fn`. And is there still a `Num Lock` button? The button may toggle the meaning of these keys so they become a numpad *without* `Fn`. Investigate.

Comment: == 27.06.2023 13:40 it is a Notebook keyboard withpout separate numpad but with NumLock etc. I have all tried, Tahanks, Regards